# Почему выбрасывает ошибку mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER marketing_list_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON cms_offers
FOR EACH ROW
begin
if NEW.status = 'active' 
then UPDATE marketing_credits_requests SET sum_s=NEW.ammount, statut=NEW.status WHERE id_req=old.id;
else then UPDATE marketing_credits_requests SET  statut=NEW.status WHERE id_req=old.id;
end;
```

и ошибка

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Делал все по докам mysql, версия 5.5.25

Comment: имен полей  такие и должны быть `aMMount`, `statuT` ?

Comment: @teran да все так и называется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так, после ELSE не нужен THEN он нужен для ELSEIF и IF что бы отделить условие, и после всего блока условий его надо закрыть

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER marketing_list_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON cms_offers
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.status = 'active' 
        THEN UPDATE marketing_credits_requests SET sum_s=NEW.ammount, statut=NEW.status WHERE id_req=old.id;
        ELSE UPDATE marketing_credits_requests SET  statut=NEW.status WHERE id_req=old.id;
    END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

**UPDATE P.S.:** добавил разделитель

Comment: та же проблема осталась

Comment: @JohnFrost обернул в разделитель, вероятно ругается на то что триггер заканчивается на первом условии